# Curvature formula derivation.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, curvature

Wanting to derive formula for curvature I stumbled upon problem with calculation. 
The formula I wanted to derive is as follows:
$$\kappa=\frac{\lvert\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\times\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\rvert}{\lvert\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\rvert^3}$$

One of the definitions of curvature is rate of change of unit tangent vector with respect to arc length. i.e. 
$$\lvert\frac{d\hat T}{ds}\rvert=\lvert\frac{d\hat T}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{ds}\rvert=\lvert\frac{d\hat T}{dt}\rvert\cdot\frac{1}{\lvert ds/dt\rvert}$$
Therefore:
$$\kappa=\lvert\frac{d}{dt}\Biggl(\frac{d\vec r/dt}{\lvert d\vec r/dt\rvert}\Biggr)\rvert\cdot\frac{1}{\lvert d\vec r/dt\rvert}$$
Calculating derivative by quotient rule and taking into account absolute value I am left with:
$$\lvert\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\cdot\lvert d\vec r/dt\rvert-\frac{[d\vec r/dt]^2}{\lvert d\vec r/dt\rvert}\frac {d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\rvert\cdot\frac{1}{\lvert d\vec r/dt\rvert^3}$$since $$[d\vec r/dt]^2 = \lvert d\vec r/dt\rvert^2$$whole expression with absolute value reduces to zero...

Comment: What does $[d\vec r/dt]^2$ even mean??!! You can't differentiate like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: To differentiate $|d\vec r/dt|$, you need to differentiate
$$\left|\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\right|^2 = \frac{d\vec r}{dt}\cdot\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$$
by the product rule and then deduce what you want by the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The $$[d \vec r/dt]^2$$ means squared term, not second derivative. I must be still doing something wrong, as I still get that derivative is zero.

Comment: I don't know what the square of a vector is. Tell me what you got when you did my hint.

Comment: $$\frac d{dt} \Biggl(\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\cdot\frac {d\vec r}{dt}\Biggl)=2\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\cdot\frac {d\vec r}{dt}$$
Since
$$\frac{d}{dt}\lvert\vec dr/dt\rvert^2=2\lvert\vec dr/dt\rvert\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\lvert\vec dr/dt\rvert$$
we get 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\lvert\vec dr/dt\rvert=\Biggl(\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\cdot\frac {d\vec r}{dt}\Biggr)\frac{1}{\lvert\vec dr/dt\rvert}$$

Carrying differentiation I get 
$$\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\cdot{\lvert\vec dr/dt\rvert}-\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\cdot(d\vec r/dt)^2\frac{1}{\lvert\vec dr/dt\rvert}$$

Comment: You're saying that $(\vec v\cdot\vec w)\vec w$ is $\vec v\cdot (\vec w)^2$, which, as I complained, means nothing. The second term should be $\Big(\dfrac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}\cdot\dfrac{d\vec r}{dt}\Big)\dfrac{d\vec r}{dt}\,\dfrac1{|d\vec r/dt|}$.  But — otherwise — good job!